# Increase line width without stochastic bars ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, roc

Does anyone know if it's possible to increase the line width in ggplot2 in a smooth fashion without adding random lines that stick out? Here's my original line plot and with size increased to 5:

```
> ggplot(curve.df, aes(x=recall, y=precision, color=cutoff)) +
>   geom_line(size=1)
```

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

Ideally, the final image would look something like the following plot from the PRROC Package, but I have another problem with plotting from there in that gridlines and ablines do not correspond to the axis tickmarks.

Here I first called

```
> grid()
```

and then called

```
> abline(v=seq(0,1,.2), h=seq(0,1,.2))
```

[image][image]

Honestly would appreciate any way to be able to draw this curve with a wider line to see clear colors and a grid that corresponds to the axis tickmarks. Thanks!

Here's a sample of the data from cutoff .5 to .7:

```
> dput(output)
structure(list(recall = c(0.0237648530331457, 0.024390243902439, 
0.0250156347717323, 0.0256410256410256, 0.0256410256410256, 0.0268918073796123, 
0.0275171982489056, 0.0281425891181989, 0.0293933708567855, 0.0300187617260788, 
0.0300187617260788, 0.0300187617260788, 0.0306441525953721, 0.0312695434646654, 
0.0312695434646654, 0.0312695434646654, 0.0318949343339587, 0.0318949343339587, 
0.0318949343339587, 0.032520325203252, 0.0331457160725453, 0.0331457160725453, 
0.0337711069418387, 0.034396497811132, 0.034396497811132, 0.0350218886804253, 
0.0356472795497186, 0.0356472795497186, 0.0362726704190119, 0.0362726704190119, 
0.0362726704190119, 0.0387742338961851, 0.0387742338961851, 0.0387742338961851, 
0.0393996247654784, 0.0400250156347717, 0.0400250156347717, 0.040650406504065, 
0.040650406504065, 0.040650406504065, 0.0412757973733583, 0.0419011882426517, 
0.042526579111945, 0.0431519699812383, 0.0431519699812383, 0.0437773608505316, 
0.0444027517198249, 0.0450281425891182, 0.0456535334584115, 0.0456535334584115, 
0.0462789243277048, 0.0469043151969981, 0.0469043151969981, 0.0469043151969981, 
0.0469043151969981, 0.0475297060662914, 0.0481550969355847, 0.0481550969355847, 
0.0494058786741714, 0.0494058786741714, 0.0494058786741714, 0.0494058786741714, 
0.0512820512820513, 0.0512820512820513, 0.0531582238899312, 0.0537836147592245, 
0.0537836147592245, 0.0537836147592245, 0.0550343964978111, 0.0556597873671044, 
0.0556597873671044, 0.0562851782363977, 0.0569105691056911, 0.0575359599749844, 
0.0581613508442777, 0.058786741713571, 0.0594121325828643, 0.0594121325828643, 
0.0600375234521576, 0.0606629143214509, 0.0612883051907442, 0.0625390869293308, 
0.0631644777986241, 0.0637898686679174, 0.0644152595372108, 0.0644152595372108, 
0.0644152595372108, 0.0650406504065041, 0.0650406504065041, 0.0656660412757974, 
0.0656660412757974, 0.0662914321450907, 0.066916823014384, 0.0687929956222639, 
0.0694183864915572, 0.0700437773608505, 0.0700437773608505, 0.0706691682301438, 
0.0712945590994371, 0.0712945590994371, 0.0712945590994371, 0.0712945590994371, 
0.0712945590994371, 0.0712945590994371, 0.0719199499687305, 0.0725453408380238, 
0.0725453408380238, 0.0731707317073171, 0.075046904315197, 0.075046904315197, 
0.0756722951844903, 0.0762976860537836, 0.0769230769230769, 0.0775484677923702, 
0.0775484677923702, 0.0787992495309568, 0.0794246404002502, 0.0794246404002502, 
0.0794246404002502, 0.0800500312695435, 0.0800500312695435, 0.0806754221388368, 
0.0813008130081301, 0.0813008130081301, 0.0819262038774234, 0.0825515947467167, 
0.08317698561601, 0.08317698561601, 0.0850531582238899, 0.0863039399624766, 
0.0863039399624766, 0.0869293308317699, 0.0881801125703565, 0.0888055034396498, 
0.0888055034396498, 0.0900562851782364, 0.0919324577861163, 0.0919324577861163, 
0.0925578486554096, 0.0931832395247029, 0.0931832395247029, 0.0931832395247029, 
0.0938086303939962, 0.0944340212632895, 0.0944340212632895, 0.0956848030018762, 
0.0956848030018762, 0.0963101938711695, 0.0963101938711695, 0.0963101938711695, 
0.0963101938711695, 0.0975609756097561, 0.0981863664790494, 0.0988117573483427, 
0.0988117573483427, 0.099437148217636, 0.099437148217636, 0.100062539086929, 
0.100687929956223, 0.101313320825516, 0.103189493433396, 0.103814884302689, 
0.103814884302689, 0.103814884302689, 0.105065666041276, 0.105691056910569, 
0.106316447779862, 0.106316447779862, 0.106941838649156, 0.107567229518449, 
0.107567229518449, 0.107567229518449, 0.108192620387742, 0.108818011257036, 
0.109443402126329, 0.110694183864916, 0.110694183864916, 0.111319574734209, 
0.111319574734209, 0.111319574734209, 0.112570356472795, 0.114446529080675, 
0.114446529080675, 0.114446529080675, 0.114446529080675, 0.115071919949969, 
0.115697310819262, 0.118198874296435, 0.119449656035022, 0.119449656035022, 
0.119449656035022, 0.120700437773609, 0.120700437773609, 0.121325828642902, 
0.121951219512195, 0.121951219512195, 0.122576610381488, 0.122576610381488, 
0.122576610381488, 0.122576610381488, 0.123202001250782, 0.123827392120075, 
0.125703564727955, 0.127579737335835, 0.127579737335835, 0.127579737335835, 
0.127579737335835, 0.127579737335835, 0.128830519074422, 0.128830519074422, 
0.129455909943715, 0.129455909943715, 0.130706691682301, 0.131957473420888, 
0.132582864290181, 0.132582864290181, 0.134459036898061, 0.135084427767355, 
0.136335209505941, 0.136960600375235, 0.136960600375235, 0.136960600375235, 
0.137585991244528, 0.138211382113821, 0.138211382113821, 0.138836772983114, 
0.140712945590994, 0.140712945590994, 0.141338336460288, 0.141338336460288, 
0.141963727329581, 0.141963727329581, 0.149468417761101), precision = c(0.584615384615385, 
0.590909090909091, 0.597014925373134, 0.602941176470588, 0.594202898550725, 
0.597222222222222, 0.594594594594595, 0.6, 0.602564102564103, 
0.607594936708861, 0.6, 0.592592592592593, 0.597560975609756, 
0.595238095238095, 0.588235294117647, 0.581395348837209, 0.579545454545455, 
0.573033707865168, 0.566666666666667, 0.571428571428571, 0.56989247311828, 
0.563829787234043, 0.568421052631579, 0.572916666666667, 0.56701030927835, 
0.571428571428571, 0.575757575757576, 0.57, 0.568627450980392, 
0.563106796116505, 0.557692307692308, 0.553571428571429, 0.548672566371681, 
0.543859649122807, 0.538461538461538, 0.542372881355932, 0.53781512605042, 
0.541666666666667, 0.537190082644628, 0.532786885245902, 0.536585365853659, 
0.540322580645161, 0.544, 0.543307086614173, 0.5390625, 0.538461538461538, 
0.537878787878788, 0.537313432835821, 0.540740740740741, 0.536764705882353, 
0.536231884057971, 0.531914893617021, 0.528169014084507, 0.524475524475524, 
0.520833333333333, 0.524137931034483, 0.523809523809524, 0.52027027027027, 
0.526666666666667, 0.52317880794702, 0.516339869281046, 0.512987012987013, 
0.522292993630573, 0.518987341772152, 0.527950310559006, 0.52760736196319, 
0.524390243902439, 0.521212121212121, 0.526946107784431, 0.529761904761905, 
0.526627218934911, 0.526315789473684, 0.526011560693642, 0.528735632183908, 
0.531428571428571, 0.531073446327684, 0.527777777777778, 0.524861878453039, 
0.524590163934426, 0.527173913043478, 0.52972972972973, 0.529100529100529, 
0.528795811518325, 0.525773195876289, 0.528205128205128, 0.525510204081633, 
0.517587939698492, 0.52, 0.517412935323383, 0.51980198019802, 
0.51219512195122, 0.514563106796116, 0.514423076923077, 0.52132701421801, 
0.523584905660377, 0.523364485981308, 0.52093023255814, 0.518348623853211, 
0.520547945205479, 0.518181818181818, 0.515837104072398, 0.511210762331839, 
0.508928571428571, 0.506666666666667, 0.508849557522124, 0.5, 
0.497854077253219, 0.497872340425532, 0.504201680672269, 0.502092050209205, 
0.504166666666667, 0.506224066390041, 0.506172839506173, 0.508196721311475, 
0.506122448979592, 0.510121457489879, 0.51004016064257, 0.508, 
0.503968253968254, 0.498054474708171, 0.496124031007752, 0.494252873563218, 
0.492424242424242, 0.490566037735849, 0.488805970149254, 0.488888888888889, 
0.488970588235294, 0.487179487179487, 0.489208633093525, 0.48936170212766, 
0.487632508833922, 0.48943661971831, 0.493006993006993, 0.491349480968858, 
0.487972508591065, 0.491467576791809, 0.496621621621622, 0.493288590604027, 
0.486842105263158, 0.486928104575163, 0.485342019543974, 0.482200647249191, 
0.482315112540193, 0.482428115015974, 0.480891719745223, 0.481132075471698, 
0.479623824451411, 0.48125, 0.479750778816199, 0.478260869565217, 
0.476780185758514, 0.478527607361963, 0.480122324159021, 0.480243161094225, 
0.478787878787879, 0.478915662650602, 0.477477477477477, 0.479041916167665, 
0.476331360946746, 0.47787610619469, 0.478260869565217, 0.479768786127168, 
0.478386167146974, 0.474285714285714, 0.473239436619718, 0.472067039106145, 
0.472222222222222, 0.470914127423823, 0.472375690607735, 0.471232876712329, 
0.464864864864865, 0.463611859838275, 0.46505376344086, 0.466487935656836, 
0.467914438502674, 0.468253968253968, 0.467018469656992, 0.467191601049869, 
0.464751958224543, 0.463541666666667, 0.465116279069767, 0.465648854961832, 
0.464467005076142, 0.462121212121212, 0.46095717884131, 0.462311557788945, 
0.461346633416459, 0.466666666666667, 0.466992665036675, 0.465853658536585, 
0.463592233009709, 0.463942307692308, 0.462829736211031, 0.463007159904535, 
0.464285714285714, 0.463182897862233, 0.462264150943396, 0.460093896713615, 
0.456876456876457, 0.455813953488372, 0.454965357967667, 0.456221198156682, 
0.457858769931663, 0.461538461538462, 0.460496613995485, 0.458426966292135, 
0.453333333333333, 0.452328159645233, 0.45374449339207, 0.452747252747253, 
0.453947368421053, 0.451965065502183, 0.453362255965293, 0.455723542116631, 
0.456896551724138, 0.455913978494624, 0.459401709401709, 0.460554371002132, 
0.461864406779661, 0.463002114164905, 0.461052631578947, 0.460084033613445, 
0.460251046025105, 0.459459459459459, 0.457556935817805, 0.457731958762887, 
0.458248472505092, 0.456389452332657, 0.456565656565657, 0.455645161290323, 
0.455823293172691, 0.454909819639279, 0.449248120300752), cutoff = c(0.7, 
0.695652173913043, 0.694444444444444, 0.694117647058824, 0.693333333333333, 
0.692307692307692, 0.691358024691358, 0.691176470588235, 0.690140845070423, 
0.689655172413793, 0.688888888888889, 0.688311688311688, 0.6875, 
0.686746987951807, 0.686567164179104, 0.686046511627907, 0.685714285714286, 
0.684210526315789, 0.683544303797468, 0.683333333333333, 0.680555555555556, 
0.68, 0.67948717948718, 0.67741935483871, 0.676923076923077, 
0.676056338028169, 0.675675675675676, 0.675324675324675, 0.671641791044776, 
0.671428571428571, 0.671052631578947, 0.666666666666667, 0.662650602409639, 
0.662162162162162, 0.661764705882353, 0.661538461538462, 0.658536585365854, 
0.657894736842105, 0.657534246575342, 0.657142857142857, 0.65625, 
0.653846153846154, 0.653333333333333, 0.652777777777778, 0.652173913043478, 
0.650602409638554, 0.65, 0.648648648648649, 0.647887323943662, 
0.647058823529412, 0.645569620253165, 0.643835616438356, 0.64367816091954, 
0.642857142857143, 0.641975308641975, 0.640625, 0.64, 0.639344262295082, 
0.638888888888889, 0.63855421686747, 0.63768115942029, 0.6375, 
0.636363636363636, 0.635135135135135, 0.633802816901408, 0.631578947368421, 
0.63013698630137, 0.62962962962963, 0.628571428571429, 0.627118644067797, 
0.626865671641791, 0.625, 0.623529411764706, 0.622950819672131, 
0.622222222222222, 0.621951219512195, 0.621621621621622, 0.621212121212121, 
0.619718309859155, 0.619047619047619, 0.618421052631579, 0.617647058823529, 
0.617283950617284, 0.616438356164384, 0.615384615384615, 0.614035087719298, 
0.613333333333333, 0.6125, 0.611940298507463, 0.611764705882353, 
0.61038961038961, 0.609375, 0.609195402298851, 0.608695652173913, 
0.608108108108108, 0.607594936708861, 0.606060606060606, 0.605633802816901, 
0.605263157894737, 0.604938271604938, 0.604651162790698, 0.602941176470588, 
0.602739726027397, 0.602564102564103, 0.602272727272727, 0.6, 
0.597826086956522, 0.597402597402597, 0.597222222222222, 0.597014925373134, 
0.596774193548387, 0.594936708860759, 0.594202898550725, 0.593220338983051, 
0.592592592592593, 0.591549295774648, 0.590909090909091, 0.590361445783133, 
0.588235294117647, 0.586666666666667, 0.585365853658537, 0.584615384615385, 
0.583333333333333, 0.582278481012658, 0.582089552238806, 0.581081081081081, 
0.580645161290323, 0.580246913580247, 0.579710144927536, 0.578947368421053, 
0.578313253012048, 0.578125, 0.577464788732394, 0.576923076923077, 
0.575342465753425, 0.575, 0.573333333333333, 0.573170731707317, 
0.571428571428571, 0.569620253164557, 0.569230769230769, 0.568965517241379, 
0.567901234567901, 0.567567567567568, 0.567164179104478, 0.565789473684211, 
0.565217391304348, 0.564705882352941, 0.563380281690141, 0.5625, 
0.561797752808989, 0.561643835616438, 0.560975609756098, 0.560606060606061, 
0.55952380952381, 0.558823529411765, 0.558441558441558, 0.557377049180328, 
0.557142857142857, 0.556962025316456, 0.555555555555556, 0.55421686746988, 
0.554054054054054, 0.552631578947368, 0.552238805970149, 0.551282051282051, 
0.550724637681159, 0.55, 0.549295774647887, 0.547945205479452, 
0.546666666666667, 0.546511627906977, 0.544117647058823, 0.54320987654321, 
0.542168674698795, 0.541666666666667, 0.541176470588235, 0.540540540540541, 
0.53968253968254, 0.539473684210526, 0.538461538461538, 0.537313432835821, 
0.536585365853659, 0.536231884057971, 0.535714285714286, 0.535211267605634, 
0.534246575342466, 0.533333333333333, 0.532467532467532, 0.531645569620253, 
0.53125, 0.529411764705882, 0.528571428571429, 0.527777777777778, 
0.527272727272727, 0.527027027027027, 0.526315789473684, 0.525641025641026, 
0.525, 0.524590163934426, 0.524390243902439, 0.523255813953488, 
0.523076923076923, 0.522388059701492, 0.521739130434783, 0.52112676056338, 
0.520547945205479, 0.52, 0.519480519480519, 0.518987341772152, 
0.518518518518518, 0.518072289156627, 0.517647058823529, 0.515151515151515, 
0.514285714285714, 0.513888888888889, 0.513513513513513, 0.513157894736842, 
0.512820512820513, 0.5125, 0.51219512195122, 0.511627906976744, 
0.508196721311475, 0.507692307692308, 0.507462686567164, 0.507246376811594, 
0.507042253521127, 0.506849315068493, 0.506666666666667, 0.506493506493506, 
0.506329113924051, 0.505747126436782, 0.5)), .Names = c("recall", 
"precision", "cutoff"), row.names = 55:287, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A little difficult to say without a more complete example, but try `geom_smooth()` instead of `geom_line()`. This defaults to LOESS regression by default, which might get rid of the "spikes" in your data. The coloration of the line seems superfluous, given that the same value is represented on the x-axis. You can adjust the color of the gridlines with the options available in `theme()`.

Comment: Hard without a reproducible example. Might work better to just plot points - your data is so dense! If you really want lines, maybe bin the colors in to a smaller number of groups rather than a continuous color scale.

Comment: Thanks for the input! So the coloration is a correlated but different metric, cutoff versus recall for classification models.

Comment: Could you share a few lines of code to simulate a data set that demonstrates this issue? Esp. try to match the correlation of `cutoff` and the other variables. I would normally encourage a small amount of data, but I think the *density* of your data is important here.

Comment: So I actually don't know how I would simulate it, but I can dput the data at the end of the question.

Comment: Also if anyone knows how to fix the gridlines/ablines problem for normal plotting, that would work just as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `lineend = "round"` greatly improves the plot

```
ggplot(curve.df, aes(x = recall, y = precision, color = cutoff)) +
   geom_line(size = 5, lineend = "round")
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had messed with that parameter, but maybe it was linejoin or something else. Thanks either way!

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot` can't plot a single line with multiple colors. The "stochastic" bits of your plot are actually the tops and bottoms of super little short lines (that are much thicker than they are long) connecting points that are close enough together in `cutoff` to share the same color.

Luckily, your data is so dense, a line plot is actually unnecessary. We can just plot points and all the problems go away - if we make them big enough, which seems to be what you want. (You will see the individual points if your zoom in on the data excerpt provided, but I expanded the limits to make show the data density on the size of plot you are really using. The average difference in `recall` between adjacent points is .00054, so on the scale of 0 to 1 your data is very dense!)

I also show a version with a loess smoother - you can of course play with the bandwidth for more or less smoothing. This may or may not be preferable.

```
raw_plot = ggplot(df, aes(recall, precision, color = cutoff)) + 
    geom_point(size = 3) + 
    coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1)) +
    labs(title = "Raw")

df$smooth = predict(loess(precision ~ recall, data = df))
smooth_plot = ggplot(df, aes(recall, smooth, color = cutoff)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1)) + 
    labs(title = "Smooth")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(raw_plot, smooth_plot, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining everything! Given the data I gave you in the middle of the plot this works perfectly, but there are some breaks at the edges of the plot between the points. This was super helpful though!