# ggplot geom_line different line size based on condition (wrong rendering)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line plot in  `ggplot2` that has different line sized based on condition.

I accomplished this with this code:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

dat_1 <- data.frame(
  "date" =seq(as.yearmon(Sys.Date()) - 4, as.yearmon(Sys.Date()), 1/12),
  "value" = rnorm(49),
  "ID" = "A",
  "Condition" = sample(c("AA", "AB"), size = 49, replace = TRUE)
)

dat_2 <- data.frame(
  "date" =seq(as.yearmon(Sys.Date()) - 4, as.yearmon(Sys.Date()), 1/12),
  "value" = rnorm(49),
  "ID" = "B",
  "Condition" = (sample(c("AA", "AB"), size = 49, replace = TRUE))
)

dat <- rbind(dat_1, dat_2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = value, color = ID, group = ID)) + geom_line(aes(size = Condition)) +   scale_size_manual(values = c(0.5, 2.5))
```

[image]

It is what I wanted to get (This is just a dummy, so not optimized sizes).

But, if you look closer you can see that lines are actually collection of boxes and not smooth lines:[image]

How can I fix this?

It is also possible that it might be due to the fact that my x axis are `yearmon`. But they are scaled as continues (by ggplot) in this case, anyway.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861698/increase-line-width-without-stochastic-bars-ggplot/38862129#38862129

Comment: have you tried lineend and linejoin?

Comment: Thank very much or both of you. That (lineend) fixed it. I somehow missed it earlier.